# can't connect to database by executable file

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qtsql, qsqldatabase

i wrote a program that need to connect to database to insert some data , my executable file not connect to database but when i checked with code connection established! i don't know what is problem , do you know what is problem?
i use Qt to connect to database and my database is on mySql and here is how i connect :

```
soccer_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL" , "sss");
    soccer_db.setHostName(addrrFile.c_str());
    soccer_db.setDatabaseName("sss");
    soccer_db.open();
    if (!soccer_db.open()){
        emit dsignal("ssss not opened. Ckech whether server is down or change config file");
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i want to answer my question, in qt you should address your files completely not relative address, if you need to address completely you can give current directory by QtDir

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a failure because you try to open the database *twice*. The first attempt succeeds but the second one fails. Remove the first call to `open`, like this

```
soccer_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL" , "sss");
soccer_db.setHostName(addrrFile.c_str());
soccer_db.setDatabaseName("sss");
if (!soccer_db.open()){
    emit dsignal("ssss not opened. Ckech whether server is down or change config file");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i try this but nothing happened , when i try to execute binary file from terminal connection establish but when i double click on icon it fails!

Comment: Do you need a username and password? There's lots of things that can be wrong when you try to connect to a database, you shouldn't sound so surprised. Try using `soccer_db.lastError()` to find out what the error is.

Comment: thank you for your andswer ,  problem was with hostName becuase i use relative address for reading database ip address ,qt change current directory when it run binary file and can't find the ip address